# .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am working on a project in PHP and using Apache server.

Say, my project's url is myurl.com.
When i visit
http://myurl.com
it works well.

But when I visit

http://www.myurl.com OR www.myurl.com

it redirects me to http://myurl.com, dropping the www subdirectory.

I want it to stay same, like if we visit http://www.myurl.com it should keep the "www" in url.

I believe this is a .htaccess setting.
I couldn't get the settings right.

Please guide

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should open the htaccess file and search for something like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code is redirecting.
Look further here:  http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html#m0-askapache2

Comment: thanks for the response, but i couldn't get it right. i added above lines to my .htaccess which already has some code for wordpress settings (mine is a wordpress site), but the site threw "page not redirecting properly" error

Comment: If your original settings are redirecting `http://www.wesite.com/` to `http://wesite.com/` and your new setting are redirecting `http://wesite.com/` to `http://www.wesite.com/` if you have BOTH in your htaccess that would would cause a redirect loop

Comment: yes, I meant to remove this part of code. this is responsible for the redirecting and you said you don't want to redirect from "www".